# connect R with Cassandra

Tags: r, database, dataframe, cassandra, connection

I am trying to connect R with Cassandra using:

```
connect.handle <- RC.connect(host="host", port="port")
```

i have a connection, when i test it i see i have a conenction:

```
RC.describe.keyspace(connect.handle, 'keyspace')
```

i see i have to connection working.
but when i am trying to get data from Cassandra into a dataframe in R i receive an error, i tried:

```
RC.read.table(connect.handle, 'table name', convert = TRUE, na.strings 
= "NA", as.is = FALSE, dec = ".")
```

i get this error:

```
Error in RC.get.range.slices(conn, c.family, fixed = TRUE) : 
Cassandra exception: No keyspace has been specified. USE a keyspace, or 
explicitly specify keyspace.tablename
```

if i put the keyspave before the tablename like "keyspace.tablename" it does not work neither.

can anybody help me to get data from Cassandra into R?

Thanks,

Eelco

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
RC.use(connect.handle,'your keyspace')
RC.read.table(connect.handle,"your table name")
```

It worked for me to read the table from Cassandra.